# How to use javascript to find ASPxGridView in Usercontrol and then command it to perform callback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have created Usercontrol called Attach_Template and I assigned its ID as "attachTemplate" in the master page as follows:

```
<uc1:Attach_Template ID="attachTemplate" runat="server" />
```

In my usercontrol, there is ASPxGridview with ID = "gv_Attach" and ClinetInstanceName = "grid". I want to write a function to perform callback to this ASPxGridView from Master page.

I've tried the following code. It seems that it could find the control but cannot do perform callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gvAttachPerformCallback() {
        var gvAttach = document.getElementById('<%=Attach_Template.FindControl("gv_Attach").ClientID%>');
        gvAttach.PerformCallback(null);
    }
</script>
```

The following error message occured when I tried to perform callback.

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'PerformCallback'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_ClientInstanceNametopic) to access control on client side. Then call `clientInstanceName.PerformCallback()`, or in your case `grid.PerformCallback()`.

Comment: Thanks! That really works! Don't know that it can be called directly with this way.

Answer (score 1):

Test this, it will solve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gvAttachPerformCallback() {
    var gvAttach = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName('attachTemplate');
    gvAttach.PerformCallback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use the ClientInstanceName to get access to the client-side programmatic object.

Take a look at the [How to refer to a client-side control within a UserControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18373.aspx)  KB Article.